# Handling inf in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, error-handling

I am doing calculations on a data frame where I end up dividing a column by zero. I do not want to delete the row having inf values. I want to know how to handle it?

I tried converting it to NaN but doesn't work.

Also, the end goal is to use the `df['Days needed']` column and add it to `df['Time']`.

I tried this but end up erroring out on inf,

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
temp = df['Days needed'].apply(np.ceil).apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(x, unit='D'))
df['Day'] = df['Time'] + temp
```

I get error as

> OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer on temp.

Comment: Any sample data and expected output?

Comment: if you don't need to do calcs on them, but want to keep them you could do, `df.loc[df['Time'].isnul()==False,'Day'] = df['Time'] + temp` I'm assuming you've changed them to nan in the above.

Comment: You can also just replace your inf values with NaN if you don't care about preserving them: `df['Time'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)`. Your calcs should evaluate to NaN in cases where you had an Inf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Time'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```